# How to debug Two Scoops of Django project skeleton on production server running gunicorn

Tags: django, gunicorn, django-1.5

I don't get a traceback from the Two Scoops project (https://github.com/twoscoops/django-twoscoops-project).

I'm running a Ubuntu 12.04 production server on Virtualbox and I setup gunicorn. I'm trying to learn how to setup a production server so I can host it on Digital Ocean. So far, I've been able to get gunicorn to run by typing this in /myproject/myproject/ (the same directory as my manage.py):

```
gunicorn wsgi # run this in the same directory as wsgi.py
```

Then I type:

```
curl localhost:8000
```

But I only get back:

```
<\h1\> Whoops! <\h1>
```

I did the following:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings.production
```

But I still get the same "whoops" page. Any thoughts on how I can get the Python traceback or Django debug page to work?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to turn on the debugging in a production setup.

You have to goto /settings/base.py and set `DEBUG = True`. It was False by default.

Comment: you shouldn't really, use apache error log or [sentry](https://getsentry.com/) instead! but if you really need, it's better if you do it in `settings/production.py`...